# SSIS Package - Joining two tables

Tags: sql, join, ssis, merge, package

I have two access db sources both with the same columns representing data from different time periods.  The files have two identity columns UPC and StoreNbr.  The resulting table within the DB being inserted to has the two identity columns and the data columns from each file "concatenated" into one table as seen below.:

File 1 Columns:

UPC StoreNbr data1 data2 data3

File 2 Columns:

UPC StoreNbr data1 data2 data3

DB Table Columns:

UPC StoreNbr data1(File 1) data2(File 1) data3(File 1) data1(File 2) data2(File 2)  data3(File 2)

I am new to SSIS and have been confronted with the task of merging these two sources into one table to insert into the final DB table. Can I join the two tables on the identity colummns and then insert the data into one result set?  FYI, this was originally imported in one filed reflecting the layout of the DB table but the client had the bright idea to split it into two files.  Any direction is very appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look something like this.

[image]

The sources *must* be sorted by the join keys. In your case `UPC` AND `StoreNbr`

In the merge join editor you can select which columns from the different files that will continue on the flow. You can also give them an alias in order to differentiate two similarly named columns.

After that you can just dump it all back into your DB. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go right now.  I was not sorting the input files previous to attempting to merge join.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether an item can exist in one Access source and not in another source, an alternative to TsSkTo's implementation would be to route it as

```
[Access Source 1]
         |
[Lookup Transformation to Access Source 2]
         |
[OLE DB Destination]
```

- [Lookup Transformation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx)