# How to add a Select query that needs 2 dbs to a package?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am updating an existing package with a Data Flow task.  Currently, this data flow task has 2 steps:

1. *OLE DB Source* that points to a source connection and includes a sql query
2. *OLE DB Destination*

I need to update the *OLE DB Source* with a more complex query that joins data from 2 different databases.  This query is already built and has a Group By clause, 4 or 5 Where criteria, and an Order by clause to boot.  It works like a charm when run manually. The problem is that the *OLE DB Source* only allows 1 data connection.

According to my [searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816601/ssis-package-joining-two-tables) around the net, I need to create the 2 different data sources and then merge them with a Merge Join step.  However, this looks like I'll need to effectively rebuild my entire query as a series of steps. I'd rather not do this.

Is there a way for me to just copy and paste my Select query (which, again, pulls from 2 DBs) into the package without having to completely rebuild it?

Comment: You can act as a single connection, but you may have to make the "other" database visible to the "first" one. You can add a set of synonyms which point to the "other" database objects. Then you can write a query in the "first" database which uses synonyms AND internal objects. It's like a single point of access. However this solution will bring security and architecture implications. Hope it helps anyway..

Comment: Would database links be useful for something like this? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12083

Comment: There is no problem with joining two db's. If it works when run manually in SSMS then it should work in an OLEDB source. What actual error do you get?

Comment: @ElectricLlama, sorry for the wait.  I had to put this on hold for a bit.  The odd part is that I get no error at all, it just returns 0 records.  Running the exact same query in SSMS returns 80+ records.  Could it be because my package (which is on the destination server) is trying to pull from 2 DBs AND move the data to a DB on another server?

Comment: No. Either you're accidentally pulling from the wrong database or there is some difference you don't realise in your query. Forget about cross database being an issue - it isn't. Cross SERVER _can_ be. If it runs in SSMS it should run in that source. Can you post the query? Note that without giving us all the info straight up we have to go back and forth and ask for it, and also while you are taking the time to post the query you might notice your issue. Lastly, I suggest you use SQL Profiler to capture the query in both cases. Again whilst setting this up you might notice the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the login you use for the connection has proper acces you should be able to use all DBs on the server as long as you fully qualify your table names. i.e.

```
select a, b
from bd1.dbo.table1 join
 db2.dbo.table2
  on some_col = some_other_col
```

If that somehow doesn't work out (it should, I have some of those queries running in ssis) you could make a view in 1 database that hold the query on both databases. Again, the connecting account needs the proper permissions on all used DBs.

In case you are using something other then a select where you are not allowed to specify db/schema you can use

```
use db1
some action

use db2 
some action
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a single server and you have rights for the databases then with a oledb source you can work for multiple database. This 2 settings you need to consider...
1)you need to provide a fully qualified name for all objects. (db_name.Schema_name.object_name)
2)while connecting to a oledb source, just provide the server name and the credential for the server, don't provide any database name. leave the database name as blank for the oledb source then it will work for all the database on the server.